# Unable to convert from int to Integer in Java

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive

I have an Integer Stack and I'm working on a method to insert elements into it from a JOptionPane.
However, JOptionPane returns a string, so I parsed it into an int, but then I tried to insert the value in the stack and apparently, I need to convert it from int to Integer first.

So I tried with what every guide has been mentioning, create a new Integer object with the value of the parsedInt, but I'm getting error

```
"unexpected type
  required: class
  found:    type parameter Integer
  where Integer is a type-variable:
    Integer extends Object declared in class SizedStack"
```

This is the code I'm trying

```
public void addToStack(JOptionPane optionPane) {
    int val;
    String temp;
    temp = optionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer to insert into the stack");
    val = parseInt(temp);
    Integer valInteger = new Integer(val);
    this.push(valInteger);
}
```

line `Integer valInteger = new Integer(val);` is the one flagging the error.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Try `Integer.parseInt(temp);`

Comment: It's not recognizing the parseInt part. cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method parseInt(String)
  location: class Object

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a question very similar to this one in the past.  Maybe with `<String>` instead of `<Integer>` - but creating the problem where a type parameter hides a class out of `java.lang` with the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've declared your class similar to:

```
class SizedStack<Integer> {
```

`Integer` is now a type variable, not the class `java.lang.Integer`.

If you want it to be a generic class, write it something like:

```
class SizedStack<T> {
```

Or for an `Integer`-only stack.

```
class SizedStack {
```

If it is an `Integer`-only stack implementing a generic stack.

```
class SizedStack implements Stack<Integer> {
```

Comment: The SizedStack is just public class SizedStack<Integer> extends Stack<Integer>

Comment: Should be `public class SizedStack extends Stack<Integer>` if `Stack` is a generic class, not a generic interface.

Comment: Actually, it should be `public class SizedStack<T> extends Stack<T>`, so the user of `SizedStack` can choose the element type.

Comment: @Andreas The implementation is specific to `Integer` in this case. And `Stack` should probably be an interface, unless it is `java.util.Stack` which shouldn't be used.

Comment: Except that it seems that OP only wants it to be able to store `Integer` objects.  Perhaps `public class SizedStackOfIntegers extends Stack<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've statically imported the method `Integer.parseInt()`, I believe that you are missing the class Integer from your `parseInt()` call.

```
public void addToStack(JOptionPane optionPane) {
    int val;
    String temp;
    temp = optionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer to insert into the stack");
    val = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    Integer valInteger = new Integer(val);
    this.push(valInteger);
}
```

Changed `val = parseInt(temp);` to `val = Integer.parseInt(temp);`